# Unique jenkins job/pipeline identifier

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Was wondering if exists something in Jenkins like a unique job/pipeline Id, generated once at the job creation with only read access, so this Id can uniquely identify the job for authentication purposes.

Thanks in advance,

Juan

Comment: I believe the job name is unique. Folder is also created as a job item in Jenkins which is unique too.

Comment: Hi I mean universaly unique, way that is very dificult two different ones.

Comment: I don't think something like this exists. If you take a look into the file system or the URL structure, there is always the job name used as the identifier. So even if there was something like this, it is not used in any way.

Comment: When you say **with only read access**, what do you mean? In jenkins, if you create a pipeline, you can control user access to read only. You don't need to manage this security concern inside pipeline.

Comment: @JRichardsz, I mean that it cannot be modified/manipulated, will always be the same. Created by jenkins on job creation and only destroyed when the job is deleted.

Comment: Jenkins has a security engine. So all your jobs are already secure. I don't understand why you need an id to **authentication purposes**

Comment: @JRichardsz third party authentication, i.e. attach this id to send job results/logs whatever to the cloud, authenticate the job as valid, discard unauthorised.

Answer (score 9):

You can generate a new one if you want:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        unique_Id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, a unique identifier does not exist.

This would be a valuable addition to Jenkins.

For instance, one might have other systems that monitor Jenkins jobs.  If people rename them, the links are then broken.

If a user links the Jenkins Job by name, the underlying system could look up the id, and store that, hence linking the job.

People create, delete and rename Jenkins jobs all the time and asset management and tracking Jenkins job resources can be painful.

ID, Long Name, Short Name for Objects/People are important.  For instance, my social security number never changes, my full name can be legally changed but it very consistent and my nickname/shortname/username varies across people/systems.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BUILD_TAG` (from [Jenkins set environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project))